# xsl 2.0 multiple nesting based on different elements

Tags: xslt, nested

How do I multiple nest the following xml using xsl 2.0 based on level1 (outer), level2(middle), level3(inner)?

```
<rootNode>
   <fruits>
      <fruit>
         <level1>4</level1>
         <level2/>
         <level3/>
         <kind>orange</kind>
         <size>big</size>
         <origin>california</origin>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
         <level1>4</level1>
         <level2>2</level2>
         <level3/>
         <kind>lemon</kind>
         <size>small</size>
         <origin>florida</origin>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
         <level1>4</level1>
         <level2>2</level2>
         <level3>1</level3>
         <kind>pineapple</kind>
         <size>normal</size>
         <origin>oregon</origin>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
         <level1>5</level1>
         <level2>2</level2>
         <level3/>
         <kind>pineapple</kind>
         <size>normal</size>
         <origin>oregon</origin>
      </fruit>
      <fruit>
         <level1>5</level1>
         <level2>1</level2>
         <level3/>
         <kind>peer</kind>
         <size>big</size>
         <origin>ohio</origin>
      </fruit>
   </fruits>
</rootNode>
```

I can do it for level1 using the following xslt

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/rootNode/fruits">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="fruit" group-by="level1">
            <level1 name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
            </level1>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

However, using the output from it and doing it again for lavel2 doesn't work. Recursion function? How to write it?

Answer (score 1):

As your title says, you need to *nest* two `xsl:for-each-group` instructions, one inside the other:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/rootNode">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="fruits/fruit" group-by="level1">
        <level1 name="{current-grouping-key()}">
            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="level2">
                <level2 name="{current-grouping-key()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </level2>   
            </level1>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Demo:** https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bdxtre

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've used your answer to extend it to all 3 levels, level1, level2, level3. However, I still have a few problems. It is always nesting level1/level2/level3. If for example level2 & level3 are empty empty I should have fruit directly under level1, and level2 and level3 should be removed because they both have no elements. The same apply for level2 if level3 is empty.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this fully. It seems like you need to branch according to `<xsl:when test="current-grouping-key()"/>`.

Comment: Thanks. Based on your xsl I figured it out.